# Top variable declared globaly (ES6 Babel)

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, ecmascript-6

Exist a method to declare a function globaly from a module in ES6?
If i declare a variable like this:

```
global.variablename = function() {};
global.variablename2 = function() {};
```

This functions will be avaiable in all module that i import in my main file.
But how can i save all my functions in a file and import it globaly? If i import it the functions are not accessible from an external plugin. When they call the function, it result undefined.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: as i write in my comment, i have this problem:
When i create an ajax form with unobtrusive ajax, i set the callback for the complete event like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null,
                    new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "ajaxCallback"},
                    new { id = "ajaxForm", @class = "" }))
```

If i declare "ajaxCallback" function in the main file like this:

```
global.ajaxCallback = function() {}
```

The callback work fine. If i place it in a module and import it (in the main file), it didn't work because isn't in the global context. I must import it from a module but in the global context. Is it possible?

Comment: "*But how can i save all my functions in a file*" - isn't that exactly what your snippet is doing already?

Comment: Why do you want global functions? That's not exactly the concept of *module*arity.

Comment: *"Exist a method to declare a function globaly from a module in ES6?"* Other than would you posted, no.

Comment: My problem is that this functions must be called by another plugin (isn't my plugin). Is unobstrusive ajax for c#. They call the oncomplete function and if i didn't declare it with global in the main file the callback fail. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3):

Attach the variable to `window` would work but not recommended such as:

`window.someVariable = 'foo'`

Alternatively in webpack you could use the library property on output via:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html#examples

Comment: Wouldn't that essentially be the same thing? It still would have to attach to the `window` object eventually, correct?